# how can I allow robot.txt in my .htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, robots.txt

I am trying to make robots.txt and favicon.ico accessible through http.  They are both in my app's root directory.  I want them to be able to go to mydomain.com/robots.txt and my robots.txt file and same with favicon.ico.  I have looked at other examples on the internet and stack overflow but I can't seem to get it working for my specific .htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/server-status
RewriteRule ^folder1/(.+)?$ folder1/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^folder2/(.+)?$ folder2/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^folder3/(.+)?$ folder3/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^folder4/(.+)?$ folder4/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^robots.txt [L]
RewriteRule ^favicon.ico [L]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule !\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png|css|js|php|htaccess|xml|htm|html|swf|pdf)$ index.php

<ifModule mod_headers.c>

# Expires after 1 month
<filesMatch ".(css|js)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000"
</filesMatch>

# Expires after 1 day
<filesMatch ".(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|x-icon)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=31536000"
</filesMatch>
</ifModule>
```

Comment: Why though ...? How do your automatic redirect to HTTPS and HSTS not cover all possible scenarios, security-wise? Which clients who don't speak HTTPS do you expect(?), and what would they do with your sitemap, if anything else is HTTPS anyway ...?

Comment: i fixed this i just have to wait an hour before accepting my own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/server-status
RewriteRule ^folder1/(.+)?$ folder1/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^folder2/(.+)?$ folder2/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^folder3/(.+)?$ folder3/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^folder4/(.+)?$ folder4/$1 [L]
RewriteRule "^robots.txt$" "robots.txt" [L]
RewriteRule "^favicon.ico$" "favicon.ico" [L]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule !\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png|css|js|php|htaccess|xml|htm|html|swf|pdf)$ index.php

<ifModule mod_headers.c>

# Expires after 1 month
<filesMatch ".(css|js)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000"
</filesMatch>

# Expires after 1 day
<filesMatch ".(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|x-icon)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=31536000"
</filesMatch>
</ifModule>
```